# Get nodes where child node contains an attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

Suppose I have the following XML:

```
<book category="CLASSICS">
  <title lang="it">Purgatorio</title>
  <author>Dante Alighieri</author>
  <year>1308</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="CLASSICS">
  <title lang="it">Inferno</title>
  <author>Dante Alighieri</author>
  <year>1308</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>
```

I would like to do an xpath that gets back all book nodes that have a title node with a language attribute of "it".

My attempt looked something like this:

`//book[title[@lang='it']]`

But that didn't work. I expect to get back the nodes:

```
<book category="CLASSICS">
  <title lang="it">Purgatorio</title>
  <author>Dante Alighieri</author>
  <year>1308</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="CLASSICS">
  <title lang="it">Inferno</title>
  <author>Dante Alighieri</author>
  <year>1308</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>
```

Any hints?

Comment: What XPath implementation is this?

Answer (score 198):

Try

```
//book[title/@lang = 'it']
```

This reads:

- get all `book` elements

  - that have at least one `title`

    - which has an attribute `lang`

      - with a value of `"it"`

You may find [this](http://www.rpbourret.com/xml/XPathIn5.htm) helpful — it's an article entitled ["XPath in Five Paragraphs"](http://www.rpbourret.com/xml/XPathIn5.htm) by Ronald Bourret.

But in all honesty, `//book[title[@lang='it']]` and the above should be equivalent, unless your XPath engine has "issues." So it could be something in the code or sample XML that you're not showing us -- for example, your sample is an XML fragment. Could it be that the root element has a namespace, and you aren't counting for that in your query? And you only told us that it didn't work, but you didn't tell us what results you did get.

Comment: How to do the same if `title` is not a direct child of `book`, but somewhere deeper and we don't know where exactly? `//book[/title/@lang = 'it']` doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Martin, you could use //book[.//title/@lang = 'it']. I believe the trick is the "." in the beginning of the condition.

Comment: Thanks for the link, excellent article. I've been using xPath for years but this really helped me understand the underlying logic!

Answer (score 64):

Years later, but a useful option would be to utilize XPath Axes (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp). More specifically, you are looking to use the *descendants* axes.

I believe this example would do the trick:

```
//book[descendant::title[@lang='it']]
```

This allows you to select all `book` elements that contain a child `title` element (regardless of how deep it is nested) containing language attribute value equal to 'it'.

I cannot say for sure whether or not this answer is relevant to the year 2009 as I am not 100% certain that the XPath Axes existed at that time. What I can confirm is that they do exist today and I have found them to be extremely useful in XPath navigation and I am sure you will as well.

Comment: This is great, **descendant** or other axes can give us an opportunity to have locate `node` as its `attribute`,not hierarchical way as usual .

Answer (score 15):

```
//book[title[@lang='it']]
```

is actually equivalent to

```
 //book[title/@lang = 'it']
```

I tried it using vtd-xml, both expressions spit out the same result...
what xpath processing engine did you use? I guess it has conformance issue
Below is the code

```
import com.ximpleware.*;
public class test1 {
  public static void main(String[] s) throws Exception{
      VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
      if (vg.parseFile("c:/books.xml", true)){
          VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
          AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
          ap.selectXPath("//book[title[@lang='it']]");
                  //ap.selectXPath("//book[title/@lang='it']");

          int i;
          while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
              System.out.println("index ==>"+i);
          }
          /*if (vn.endsWith(i, "< test")){
             System.out.println(" good ");  
          }else
              System.out.println(" bad ");*/

      }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 that its a compliance issue and that the syntax generates the same nodeset.  Similar code in C# also works.

Comment: -1: Mr. Zhang, I was trying to do you a favor by removing code not relevant to the question. It allowed me to not downvote you, which I now feel I have to. Note that no other answer included code to call call the query.

Comment: +1: Because I can't figure out what Mr. Saunders is talking about - no other answer added ANY code, and this answer shows the code used so we can 1: validate his methods and 2: perform his test ourselves.  The code is short and easy to read.  I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I would think your own suggestion is correct, however the xml is not quite valid. If you are running the `//book[title[@lang='it']]` on `<root>[Your"XML"Here]</root>` then the free online xPath testers such as one [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) will find the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this xPath expression:

```
//book/title[@lang='it']/..
```

That should give you all book nodes in "it" lang

Comment: the result of that expression is the title nodes, not the book nodes

Comment: That is not true. It will return book nodes (these two dots at the end are to aim at the upper node of title node).