# lxml: get element with a particular child element?

Tags: python, lxml

Working in lxml, I want to get the `href` attribute of all links with an `img` child that has `title="Go to next page"`.

So in the following snippet:

```
<a class="noborder" href="StdResults.aspx">
<img src="arrowr.gif" title="Go to next page"></img>
</a>
```

I'd like to get `StdResults.aspx` back.

I've got this far:

```
next_link = doc.xpath("//a/img[@title='Go to next page']") 
print next_link[0].attrib['href']
```

But `next_link` is the `img`, not the `a` tag - how can I get the `a` tag?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XPath : Get nodes where child node contains an attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457638/xpath-get-nodes-where-child-node-contains-an-attribute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `a/img...` to `a[img...]`: (the brackets sort of mean "such that")

```
import lxml.html as lh

content='''<a class="noborder" href="StdResults.aspx">
<img src="arrowr.gif" title="Go to next page"></img>
</a>'''

doc=lh.fromstring(content)
for elt in doc.xpath("//a[img[@title='Go to next page']]"):
    print(elt.attrib['href'])

# StdResults.aspx
```

Or, you could go even farther and use

```
"//a[img[@title='Go to next page']]/@href"
```

to retrieve the values of the href attributes.

Comment: thanks, I always thought a[@..] could only specify the attributes. actually I wonder if there is any good place for a reference or samples of lxml for such confusions?

Answer (score 0):

You can also select the parent node or arbitrary ancestors by using `//a/img[@title='Go to next page']/parent::a` or `//a/img[@title='Go to next page']/ancestor::a` respectively as XPath expressions.