# Getting parent tag id with lxml

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, lxml, lxml.html

I am trying scrape a dummy site and get the parent tag of one that I am searching for. Heres the structure of the code I am searching for:

```
<div id='veg1'>
    <div class='veg-icon icon'></div>
</div>

<div id='veg2'>
</div>
```

Heres my python script:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

req = requests.get('https://mysite.com')
vegTree = html.fromstring(req.text)
veg = vegTree.xpath('//div[div[@class="veg-icon vegIco"]]/id')
```

When veg is printed I get an empty list but I am hoping to get veg1. As I am not getting an error I am not sure what has gone wrong. As I was it in a previous question and followed that syntax. See [lxml: get element with a particular child element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892219/lxml-get-element-with-a-particular-child-element?rq=1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few things are wrong in your xpath:

- you are checking for the classes `veg-icon vegIco`, while in the HTML the child `div` has `veg-icon icon`
- attributes are prepended with `@`: `@id` instead of `id`

The fixed version:

```
//div[div[@class="veg-icon icon"]]/@id
```