# Selecting parent element when child has a specific value of attribute using elementree xpath in Python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, attributes, parent-child

I'm trying to use XPath expressions using Python's ElementTree. I'm having difficulty extracting parent elements whos chilrens has a specific attribute value. These are not in the examples [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), and I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457638/xpath-get-nodes-where-child-node-contains-an-attribute), this doesn't work.

My XML doc looks as follows:

```
<Transactions>
<Transaction>
    <Project code="abc">
        <Description>blah blah</Description>
        <StartDate>2014-10-02</StartDate>
    </Project>
    <Quantity>100</Quantity>
    <Price>
        <Currency code="EUR" />
        <Value>100</Value>
    </Price>
</Transaction>
<Transaction>
    <Project code="def">
        <Description>something else</Description>
        <StartDate>2014-10-12</StartDate>
    </Project>
    <Quantity>4</Quantity>
    <Price>
        <Currency code="EUR" />
        <Value>2</Value>
    </Price>
</Transaction>
<Transaction>
    <Project code="abc">
        <Description>blah blah</Description>
        <StartDate>2014-11-02</StartDate>
    </Project>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <Price>
        <Currency code="EUR" />
        <Value>123</Value>
    </Price>
</Transaction></Transactions>
```

I'm trying to select all Transaction elements whos Project has an code of "abc".

I defined my root as follows:

```
transactions = ET.parse('../doc.xml').getroot();
```

This works (which returns all Transaction elements which have a Project as a child):

```
transactions.findall("Transaction[Project]")
```

This also works (which returns all Project elements which have the code of "abc"):

```
transactions.findall(".//Project[@code='abc']")
```

However I'm kind of lost on how to combine these (to get the Transaction elements whos child Project has a specific code). This doesn't work:

```
transactions.findall("Transaction[Project[@code='abc']]")
```

Nor this (which is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457638/xpath-get-nodes-where-child-node-contains-an-attribute)):

```
transactions.findall("Transaction[Project/@code='abc']")
```

I have already spend more than 4 hours trying to solve this problem :(. If anyone is able to answer this question for me that would be very helpful!

Kind regards,

Diederik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using (or if you would switch to) `lxml.etree` and would use the `.xpath()` method, then your expression would work as is:

```
transactions.xpath("Transaction[Project[@code='abc']]")
```

Comment: Wow! I just switched from xml.etree.ElementTree to lxml.etree. Not only do my xpath expressions now work, it is also literally ten times faster!! Thank you alecxe!!